# Is there a simple way to write a model with firms/sectors with different demand elasticities?

Tags: microeconomics, supply-and-demand, industrial-organisation, profits

I would like to write down a model where there are firms with different demand elasticities: For some firm's total profits increase and decrease a lot with increases and decreases in demand for their product. Others can change supply or costs in a way that changes in demand don't change profits as much. Is there a simple way to write a model with those features?

Comment: What kind of market is this exactly? Doesn't look like perfect comp.